# codeigniter data passing controller->library->view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter problem. Im trying to send data from a controller , to a library , to a view.

i get this error in the view:

```
Message: Undefined variable: crimes
```

FileName: views/crime_view.php

Line: 45

while debugging , i dump the $data variable, and get:

[image]

that shows that my variables exist.

in the library , im getting the controller data by using:

```
$data[] = $componentData;
```

that would not work in this case. but if i in the library do:

```
$data['crimes'] = "test";
```

then it will work. for some reason it wont process the incomming arrays from the controller.

how can i get this to work?

full code:

```
    function renderComponent($componentData = array())   
    {
        $data[] = $componentData; // stores controller variables.
        $data['rankDetails'] = $this->CI->user->rank_for_xp($userId);

        var_dump($data);

        $this->CI->load->view('components/crime/views/crime_view', $data);
    }
```

example from the controller:
[image]

Q: How can i fix this to get it passing the variables needed? so i acually can get to use the $wait variable in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a two dimensional array.

I think somewhere `$data[] = ...` must be `$data = ...`

to debug your arrays you could do like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

This shows clearly that your array is in another array...